# Spring/H2 console connected to database but not showing any data from it

Tags: java, spring, database, h2

I want to connect my database from spring to h2 console but when i do it it doesn't show any tables in it, i tried every solutions from stackoverflow and google but nothing seems  o help
this is my application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

name of my database if Data.sql and is stored in recources

content of pom.xml:

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.3.RELEASE
 

nameless
project
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
expense
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[![test connection][1]][1]

[image: after connection]

and by db:

```
insert into user values (1,'Siamak', 'Codeengine11@gmail.com')
insert into user values (2,'John', 'John@john.com')
insert into user values (3,'Adam', 'adam@adam.com')


insert into category values (1,'Travel')
insert into category values (2,'Auto Loan')
insert into category  values (3,'Travel')


insert into expense values (100,'New York Business Trip','2019-06-16T17:00:00.000Z','New York',1,1)
insert into expense values (101,'Ford Mustang Payment','2019-06-15T15:00:00.000Z','Los Angeles',2,2)
insert into expense values(102,'Grand Canyon Trip With Family','2019-06-15T15:00:00.000Z','Arizona',3,1)
```

model:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
     
    private String name;
    
    private String email;
    
}
```

when i delete:

```
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

h2 console gives me following error:

```
Database "mem:testdb" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200] 90149/90149
```

Comment: Share your entity and data.sql

Comment: check your username

Comment: Check the database with the h2 console in the browser:  http://localhost:8082

Comment: Maybe the database URL should be like this:  jdbc:h2:~/test

Comment: tried changing to  jdbc:h2:~/test  but then cant even connect

Comment: please show your logs (console output)

Answer (score 0):

My application.properties from a running application with h2 looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

# show sql commands
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: When logging in the h2-console you must set the JDBC URL. In my example: jdbc:h2:file:~/test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem

just added `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` in application.properties and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Application.properties file contents:

1. spring.jpa.show-sql=true
2. spring.h2.console.enabled=true
3. spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
4. spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=default